Where is the screen surface refraction in materials?
I am trying to find the screen space refractions in the Material tab, But for some reason I cannot seem to find it anywhere.



This is Eevee only. Are you using Eevee or Cycles ?

It is only eevee

Please add your blend file with https://blend-exchange.com/.

Screen Space Reflections is located in the Render tab. I'm not sure I understand what you are looking for.

In the image it shows screen space refractions
Under the material tab. It for some reason is not there for me

Your Blend file was saved from Blender 4.1.0. The setting name seems to have been changed from ScreenSpaceRefraction in 4.0.2 to RaytraceRefraction in 4.1.0 as shown below.

Both images are from your Blend file opened in different versions.

I really hate it when devs gratuitously change control names like that. :(

I guess that there have been changes "under the hood" to provoke the change of name. See this description in the Blender 4.1 manual.

That kind of makes my point. The 4.1 manual still calls it by "Screen Space Refractions" while the 4.1 code has renamed it "Raytrace Refractions" making all the documentation and tutorials obsolete.
